# Execute csh-script from bash and dont close csh-shell, but remain with csh-prompt

Tags: linux, bash, csh

I do have a tool that requires csh, but my default shell is bash.
I want/need to execute or source a csh-script from bash in the csh, and I want to end up with the csh-prompt after script execution.

From bash I can start the csh via `csh` and get the `csh-prompt`, then I can run any command in csh and remain with csh-prompt until I `exit`.

I also can execute a command via `csh -c 'ls'` for example, but after the command execution the csh exits and I am back in bash.

I want something like this (as an example)

```
[bash-prompt]# csh -c 'ls'
file1 file2 file3
[csh-prompt]# date
Tue Apr  2 15:33:35 CEST 2019
[csh-prompt]# exit
[bash-prompt]#
```

I don't find a way to achieve it - is it possible to execute a script and end up with the sub-shells prompt ?

Answer (score 0):

Just end your script with `csh`.

The first thing to watch for is that your script exports all variables/functions that the subshell is supposed to see.

The second thing is to watch out for non-interactive mode - you may later decide you want to run this script non-interactively (i.e., just run the script, possibly with some other commands, and exit). You'll need to handle that case separately. I've had innumerable users put `sh` at the bottom of their `.profile` or something and then wonder why my tool that was using `su` to execute commands with dropped privileges (from root) was hanging.

Comment: The "csh" at the bottom of the script executes a new shell - that is not the intention here, The reason is that I am loading some environment modules with the csh-script and those will not be loaded in the new csh at the end. I really want to have the csh-script-shel-prompt. Any other idea - or did I understand something not correctly ?